# flash xml won't cache

Tags: php, xml, flash, actionscript-3

I have a flash app that requests xml generated by a php script.  The data doesn't change much, and I would like flash to cache the xml instead of loading it every time.  I've been checking my access logs, and every single time i reload a page with the flash app on it, the php file is accessed and the xml downloaded.

I've read that flash doesn't control what is cached, as it just requests something from the browser, but nothing else that flash downloads (i.e. mp3 files that are supplied by the xml) doesn't get cached.  So I'm not really sure what that means.

I've googled the heck out of this, but everything I find is telling me how to keep flash from caching stuff.

Here's the code I used (AS3):

```
xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("info.php"));
```

It's not a huge deal but sometimes it takes 2-3 seconds to load if my host decides to respond slowly.

edit: I got the headers:

```
HEAD /beatinfo.php HTTP/1.1[CRLF]
Host: spoonhands.com[CRLF]
Connection: close[CRLF]
User-Agent: Web-sniffer/1.0.37 (+http://web-sniffer.net/)[CRLF]
Accept-Encoding: gzip[CRLF]
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,UTF-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7[CRLF]
Cache-Control: no-cache[CRLF]
Accept-Language: de,en;q=0.7,en-us;q=0.3[CRLF]
Referer: http://web-sniffer.net/[CRLF]
```

Comment: Caching is partly controlled by the headers the server sends; can you copy/paste the headers sent with info.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking at the header function. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

That is the one i always use to send html headers so that it will not be cached. I think you can send headers so that it will be cached instead.